# Compiling opencv with cmake for mingw

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake, mingw32

I'm building opencv library with cmake for mingw to be used with qt and i've been able to generate the makefilelist.
But when i type **mingw32-make** at the command prompt i get error when it's 44% built.
error says:

```
Cannot export _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_13R)p3aLLEv: symbol not found
Cannot export _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_17CmpType3allEv: symbol not found
collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: ***[bin/opencv_perf_core.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: ***[modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: ***[all] Error 2
```

Comment: Future visitors can check [this post](http://www.optimusgeek.com/?p=11). It's in portuguese but it's understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following tutorial for guidance on compiling: [OpenCV Tutorial](http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/linux-like-installation-of-opencv-230.html) opencv with mingw

The instructions are for compiling OpenCV-2.3.0, however there is no difference in the method for latest version as well.